# android studio: ImageView collision check always returns me a true value, in a always on top of other app service app I am making

Tags: android, service, imageview, collision-detection

As briefly stated in the topic, I am trying to detect collisions of 2 imageviews I show in an app that displays on top of everything, as a floating widget service.

My first imageview is p:

```
        p = new ImageView(this);
        p.setImageResource(R.drawable.k);

        pp = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
                PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);

        pp.gravity = Gravity.TOP | Gravity.LEFT;

        pp.x = 100; pp.y = 100;
        window.addView(p,pp);

                // ============= makes it a button for dragging and stuff //
        p.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

            private int initialX;
            private int initialY;
            private float initialTouchX;
            private float initialTouchY;
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent event) {

                if (gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event)) {
                    //detect tap
                    return true;
                } else {
                    // detects move and drag
                    switch (event.getAction()) {
                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                            initialX = pp.x;
                            initialY = pp.y;
                            initialTouchX = event.getRawX();
                            initialTouchY = event.getRawY();
                            return true;
                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                            return true;
                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                            pp.x = initialX + (int) (event.getRawX() - initialTouchX);
                            pp.y = initialY + (int) (event.getRawY() - initialTouchY);
                            windowManager.updateViewLayout(p, pp);
                            return true;

                    }
                    return false;
                }
            }
        });
```

So similarly to this I made another imageview q.
So I can freely drag these two imageviews.

Then trying to detect collisions with of these two imageviews, I tried 3 ways I found here on stackoverflow.

Like these:

```
public boolean CheckCollision(View v1,View v2) {
    Rect R1=new Rect(v1.getLeft(), v1.getTop(), v1.getRight(), v1.getBottom());
    Rect R2=new Rect(v2.getLeft(), v2.getTop(), v2.getRight(), v2.getBottom());
    return R1.intersect(R2);
}
public boolean chk(ImageView v1,ImageView v2) {
    Rect R1=new Rect();
    v1.getDrawingRect(R1);
    Rect R2=new Rect();
    v2.getDrawingRect(R2);

    return Rect.intersects(R1,R2);
}
public boolean chkm(ImageView v1,ImageView v2) {
    Rect R1=new Rect();
    v1.getHitRect(R1);
    Rect R2=new Rect();
    v2.getHitRect(R2);

    return R1.intersect(R2);
}
```

No matter which one i try, they always give me 'true,' at the start of the app, during my drag, or after my drag, while I can correctly detect each imageview's coordinates without problem.

If anyone can help me correct a probably stupid mistake I made, it would be greatly appreciated >.<

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I did it another way to check collision with the following

```
public boolean collide(int x1, int y1, int w1, int h1, int x2, int y2, int w2, int h2){

    boolean col = false;
    if ( (x1+w1) >= x2 &&
            (x1) <= (x2 + w2) &&
            (y1+h1) >= y2 &&
            (y1) <= (y2 + h2)
    ){
        col = true;
    }
    return col;

    //successful detection but every call is long, example in my app like ...
    //collide(pp.x, pp.y, p.getWidth(), p.getHeight(), qp.x, qp.y, q.getWidth(), q.getHeight()));
}
```

While now it 'correctly' detects collisions (in quote because of false true depending on shapes), every call is very long... And hence I feel there maybe a smarter way I don't know about...